# how to group element's of a list with respect of some information in each elements?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a list. each element's of my list is like this:

```
list[0]={'Keywords': ' foster care case aide ',
 'categoryId': '1650',
 'result': {'categoryId': '1650',
  'categoryName': 'case aide',
  'score': '1.04134220123291'}}
```

can I collect all keywords whose have the same `categoryId` in the same group. and count for each `categoryId` how many `keywords` do I have ?

please let me know if it is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `collections.defaultdict` to make a `set` for each `categoryId` and add the associated words:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(set)

for entry in list:
    kwds = entry['Keywords'].strip().split(' ')
    for word in kwds:
        output[entry['categoryId']].add(word)
```

I'm using a `set` because I assumed you don't want repeats of words within each `categoryId`.  You could instead use a `list` or some other collection.

You can then get out the size of each ID:

```
for k, v in output.items():
    print(f'ID: {k}, words: {len(v)}')

# ID: 1650, words: 4
```

---

*Responding to the comments from OP:*

If you are getting `KeyError: 'categoryId'`, that means some entries do not have the key `'categoryId'`.  If you want to simply skip those entries, you can add a small catch into the above solution:

```
for entry in list:
    # catch if there is a missing ID field
    if entry.get('categoryId', None) is None: 
        continue
  
    # otherwise the same
    kwds = entry['Keywords'].strip().split(' ')
    for word in kwds:
        output[entry['categoryId']].add(word)
```

If there is no `categoryID`, the entry will be skipped.

Note that we are also depending on a `"Keywords"` field being there as well, so you may need to add a catch for that as well.

*Or*, if you want to collect all the keywords from entries without an ID, you can just use `dict.get()` in the original solution:

```
for entry in data:
    kwds = entry['Keywords'].strip().split(' ')
    for word in kwds:
        output[entry.get('categoryId', None)].add(word)
```

Now if there is no `categoryId`, the keywords will be added to the key `None` in `output`.

Comment: I got this error `KeyError: 'categoryId'`

Comment: @elham I guess that means some of the entries of your data (in the variable you call `list`) do not have the `categoryId` key.  You would have to decide how you want to handle that or if that makes sense given the data.  But you could add an if statement which checks if there is a key for `'categoryId'` before trying to add to `output`

Comment: could you please help me with that?

Comment: @elham Sorry, that should have been `list`!  People tend to not name variables with names that Python uses (like `set` or `list` or `dict`), so I had changed it on my console.  Though using `list` still works

Comment: If I want to collect empty `categoryId` 's `'keys', should I make a list and append keys? could you also help me with this ? thanks a lot.

Comment: I meant instead of `break`

Comment: also the output is just `defaultdict(set, {'2181': {'specialist', 'support', 'web'}})` but I need all `categoryId`

Comment: why it doesn't give me all output?

Comment: @elham [see my working example here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227551/how-to-group-elements-of-a-list-with-respect-of-some-information-in-each-element); if you still have problems you may need to open a new issue, or look into how the `defaultdict` works